# Did Churchill have a hand in the sinking of the Lusitania?

Tags: winston-churchill, world-war-i

In the hope that the loss of American lives would bring the United States into World War 1, did Winston Churchill play a part in getting the Lusitania to carry ammunition so that it would be sunk by German u-boats?

There are a few claims circulating, ranging from [indirect](http://www.english.emory.edu/LostPoets/Lusitaniapapers.html) to [direct](http://lovkap.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/churchill-and-j-p-morgan-sunk-lusitania.html) action by Churchill.

The theory has certainly been proposed by some on the basis of a letter Churchill wrote to Walter Runciman, the president of Britain’s Board of Trade (quoted [here](http://www.rmslusitania.info/controversies/conspiracy-or-foul-up/)):

> It is most important to attract neutral shipping to our shores in the hope especially of embroiling the United States with Germany . . . . For our part we want the traffic — the more the better; and if some of it gets into trouble, better still.

While the conspiracy has been widely discussed, most observers prefer the "cock up" theory. Are there any grounds for suspecting a conspiracy?

Comment: Can you please add a reference where this claim is being made?

Comment: http://www.realclearhistory.com/2012/05/07/did_churchill_scheme_for_lusitania039s_sinking_2266.html

Comment: I looked at that link to find a claim, but it is about how Churchill was NOT involved. Does anyone have a link to a claim that he was?

Comment: I've added a couple of links to the question. If OP means the first claim, it looks like a motivation question. Maybe it should be improved further.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to be of the opinion that the Lusitania was shocking, but it was the [SS Sussex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_Sussex) (almost a year later) that caused the widespread outrage in the US.  This from a French flagged ship (they were already involved in the war), where no Americans died!  It should be noted that it's [RMS Lusitania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMS_Lusitania), meaning a **British-flagged** vessel...  As Lusitania's sinking seems to be held as a case of mistaken identity, cock-up seems more likely here.